# "Calls" trailer on Apple TV - how was it made?

Tags: after-effects

Does anyone have any insights into how this trailer was made?

I'm guessing After Effects - a lot of Trapcode, waveforms, chromatic aberration etc, but what about the moiré patterns in the waveforms?